# I am stuck on homework assignment Commission Calculation

Tags: java

I need to compare the total annual sales of at least three people. I need my app to calculate the additional amount that each must achieve to match or exceed the highest earner. I figured out most of it and know how to do it if there were only two people in the scenario, but getting third into the equation is throwing me for a loop! Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance! Here's what I have so far, but obviously at the end where the calculations are not going to be right.

```
package Commission3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new object AnnualCompensation
        Commission3 salesPerson[] = new Commission3[2];
        // creat two object
        salesPerson[0] = new Commission3();
        salesPerson[1] = new Commission3();
        salesPerson[2] = new Commission3();
        //new scanner input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get salesperson1 name
        System.out.println("What is your first salesperson's name?");
        salesPerson[0].name = keyboard.nextLine();

        //get salesperson1 sales total
        System.out.println("Enter annual sales of first salesperson: ");
        double val = keyboard.nextDouble();
        salesPerson[0].setAnnualSales(val);

        //get salesperson2 name
        System.out.println("What is your second salesperson's name?");
        salesPerson[1].name = keyboard.next();


        //get salesperson2 sales total
        System.out.println("Enter annual sales of second salesperson: ");
        val = keyboard.nextDouble();
        salesPerson[1].setAnnualSales(val);

        //get salesperson3 name
        System.out.println("What is your third salesperson's name?");
        salesPerson[2].name = keyboard.next();


        //get salesperson3 sales total
        System.out.println("Enter annual sales of third salesperson: ");
        val = keyboard.nextDouble();
        salesPerson[2].setAnnualSales(val);


        double total1, total2, total3;
        total1 = salesPerson[0].getTotalSales();
        System.out.println("Total sales of " + salesPerson[0].name +" is: $" + total1);
        total2 = salesPerson[1].getTotalSales();
        System.out.println("Total sales of " + salesPerson[1].name +" is: $" + total2);
        total3 = salesPerson[2].getTotalSales();
        System.out.println("Total sales of " + salesPerson[2].name +" is: $" + total3);
        if (total1 > total2) {
            System.out.print("Salesperson " + salesPerson[2].name + "'s additional amount 
        of sales that he must " + " achieve to match or exceed the higher of the 
        salesperson " + salesPerson[0].name);  
            System.out.println(" $" + (total1 - total2));
        } else if (total2 > total1) {
            System.out.print("Salesperson " + salesPerson[0].name + "'s additional amount
        of sales that he must " + " achieve to match or exceed the higher of the 
        salesperson " +  salesPerson[1].name);

            System.out.println(" $" + (total2 - total1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Both have same compensation $" + total1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *getting third into the equation is throwing me for a loop* what's the problem with using a `for` loop?

Comment: Really I do not know... I tried using- 
if (total1 > total2, total3) {
        System.out.print("Salesperson " + salesPerson[2].name + "'s additional amount 
        of sales that he must " + " achieve to match or exceed the higher of the 
        salesperson " + salesPerson[0].name);  
        System.out.println(" $" + (total1 - total2));

but obviously that is not working.

Comment: what error are you getting? array out of bounds? because your sales person array can only hold two people as the code exists now

Comment: Any question? "*the calculations are not going to be right*" is specifically not a question.

Comment: Generally, you should write down the logical high-level steps (i.e.: pseudo-code) of what you need to do in order to solve the problem, then use programming to solve it.  I think you're getting too caught up with the programming aspect without actually understanding the steps required to solve the problem.  Travis below has illustrated the kind of approach I am referring to.

Comment: array out of bound not the error... I wrote the code for two sales people and then realized it had to be for three. I thought I changed the array for three where am I missing it?

Comment: oh shoot I see it 
salesPerson[] = new Commission3[2];

should be 

salesPerson[] = new Commission3[3];

Answer (score 5):

When you take the input from the user, keep track of the highest sales thus far, and the name of the salesperson with the most sales.

Then, instead of checking total1 and total2, you can loop through all three, and compare them to the max.  If the current total is less than the max, then calculate the difference.  Otherwise, the current total is equal to the max, and you don't need to do the calculation.

I'll leave the actual code for you to figure out.

Comment: +1: *I'll leave the actual code for you to figure out.* this is what we need in this site for this kind of questions.

Comment: Just to be clear... I am not asking anyone to do my homework... I have referred to this site for many of my classes mostly reading the discussion. I am honestly stuck and have never worked with java before. I will figure out the actual code Travis and Macie thanks for your help. Luiggi and Lion your input is heard and I will file it where I think apprpriate!

Comment: @user2387429 I never stated that you wanted other people doing the homework for you. My comment was for readers of this answer because there is many people here that prefer to provide the answer in code instead of leading OP to learn by him/herself (as this answer does). Also, I upvoted your question because I think it is well written (too bad you can't see the upvotes and downvotes on a question yet).

Comment: Luiggi I apologize... I was at the end of my rope yesterday. I think I am making progress.I had the code written and it displayed correctly as long as salesPerson1 was the highest earner. I added the additional code if total2 > total1 and so on and now I do not get the calculations just display total commission of 1,2, and 3.

Comment: Luiggi I apologize... I was at the end of my rope yesterday and should have followed the advice given to Alec Baldwin today...."Don't hit send". I think I am making progress.I had the code written and it displayed correctly as long as salesPerson1 was the highest earner. I added the additional code if total2 > total1 and so on and now I do not get the calculations just display total commission of 1,2, and 3. I tried posting my code but it is too long. I am going to try to start with a new question and see if I can post it there.

Comment: my new question was marked as dup so I am at a loss now.... I am going to try D.I.C Thanks for all your help